# Debug Assertion Failed! Error during vector.earse() call

Tags: c++, vector

The code below keeps getting me a "Debug Assertion Failed!" error. I think I've isolated it to:`questions.erase(questions.begin() + number);`

The goal of the code is to randomly ask one of the questions from the test bank vector "questions". I haven't entered all the questions yet because I was trying to figure out the mechanics before hand.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
int nomen()
{
    int number;
    string ans = "No Answer";

    cout << "\nIn the Nomenclature Game you will be asked to name chemical compounds or give their UPAC symbols." << endl;

    vector<string> questions;
    vector<string> answers;

    questions.push_back("MgO");
    answers.push_back("magnesium oxide");

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    number = (rand () % questions.size()) + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << questions[number] << endl;
        questions.erase(questions.begin() + number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`questions.erase(questions.begin() + number);`  is off the end of the array.

`questions.begin()` is equivalent to position 0 and
`number` is equal to `questions.size()`

So `0 + size = size` which is 1 past the end of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

This expression

```
number = (rand () % questions.size()) + 1;
```

yields either 1 (when rand() returns any value except 0) or 2 (when rand() returns 0).

Your vectors have sizes equal to 1.

Thus in this statement

```
questions.erase(questions.begin() + number);
```

iterator `questions.begin() + number` is invalid if number is equal to 2. If number is equal to 1 then `questions.begin() + number` is equivalent 
to `questions.end()`

Also in the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << questions[number] << endl;
    questions.erase(questions.begin() + number);
}
```

you are trying to erase the same element that can be already erased in the preceeding iteration.